# SharePoint UpdateListItems using SP Services not posting error

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, spservices

How can I write jQuery code using SP Services to post to a SharePoint list? Currently, I'm using a form to get the mailing group name and details. When I run my code, I get a server 500 error. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my method.

Here's my SP Services code:

```
//Add Mail Item
$(document).on('click', '#add-group', function() {
    var title = $("input#titleName").val();
    var mga = $("input#mga").val(); 
    var serviceNews =  $( "input[type=checkbox][name=basic-news]:checked").val();
    var serviceHealth =  $( "input[type=checkbox][name=advanced-health]:checked").val();
    console.log(title);
    console.log(mga);
    console.log(serviceNews);
    console.log(serviceHealth);
    console.log(userLogin);
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "BDJ Mailing Group Subscribers",
        valuepairs: [["Title", title], ["MailingGroupAddress", mga],["ServiceNews", serviceNews],["ServiceHealth", serviceHealth]],
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            alert("success");
        }
    })
})
```

Error message:

```
/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Are `ServiceNews` and `ServiceHealth`  boolean fields ?

Comment: They are yes and no fields

Comment: whats the value in `console.log(serviceNews); , console.log(serviceHealth);` ?

Comment: "Yes" when checked

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comments, that they are Yes/No fields, you need to pass the value as 1 or 0.  The boolean fields accept value in either 1 or 0, not "Yes" or "No". Modify your code as below and try :

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-group', function() {
    var title = $("input#titleName").val();
    var mga = $("input#mga").val(); 
    var serviceNews =  $("input[type=checkbox][name=basic-news]:checked").val();

    var serviceNewsValue = (serviceNews == "Yes") ? 1 : 0;

    var serviceHealth =  $("input[type=checkbox][name=advanced-health]:checked").val();

    var serviceHealthValue = (serviceHealth == "Yes") ? 1 : 0;

    console.log(title);
    console.log(mga);
    console.log(serviceNews);
    console.log(serviceHealth);
    console.log(userLogin);
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "New",
        listName: "BDJ Mailing Group Subscribers",
        valuepairs: [["Title", title], ["MailingGroupAddress", mga],["ServiceNews", serviceNewsValue],["ServiceHealth", serviceHealthValue]],
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            alert("success");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Tried it, but got 403 forbidden error. Even if I reduce the value pairs to just Title, it will gives an error

Comment: Well the error is pretty explicit, you need to use account which has the permission to add items to the list ? Are you able to add items via the UI ?

Comment: Yes, I can add items via the GUI of SharePoint so I probably do have access